# How to set up Git server for windows xp

Tags: git, vcs

Probably this is very stupid question, but google dosen't helps. As I find out we should use gitweb and apache, but can't find any relevant tutorial about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/58425/setting-up-git-repository-on-remote-windows-server) is related. Your options seem to be msysgit or git on cygwin. [This tutorial](http://markembling.info/view/git-server-gitosis-and-cygwin-on-windows) looks pretty good.